# Duplicate, Replace or Insert backslash in C

Tags: c, arrays

This is my first question on stackoverflow, normally I would search for examples and try to understand them but I'm in a bit of a pickle.
I apologies in advance if I do not reply in a reasonable speed as this is my first time using this so here goes...

I am creating a new system to try and potentially recover deleted data and as well as the ability to permanently erase data.

What I am having trouble with is ...

if a user inputs a file path:
C:\shaving turtles

The system will not recognise the file path unless the user inputs --> C:\\shaving turtles.

So my question is how to either duplicate the backslash or replace the backslash with \\ or just get the system to recognise the \ and add another behind it (or in front)?

I am developing this in VS.

```
    gets(array1);
    arrayLength = strlen(array1);

    for(c = 0; c < arrayLength; c++) {
        if(array1[c] == '\\') {
            array1[c+1] = '\\';
        }
    }

    printf(array1);

    return 0;
}
```

I hope I havent missed anything out, Thank you for your time.

Comment: Backslashes in strings in your source code have to be doubled to make the compiler produce a single backslash in the compiled string, but your path strings at runtime should have only one backslash as the directory separator.  Why do you think you need double backslashes in path strings entered by the user at runtime?

Comment: Never use `gets`. See [here](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-56.html)

Comment: You should never use gets(). Never. Never. Never. I hope I am being clear. NEVER!! This I will never forget. Thank you for showing me this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to double-up your backslashes in the string, but if you *really* feel the need to do this, you can either copy the string into a separate buffer, or expand the string in the same buffer, but backwards...

In the first case, you don't need to use `strlen` since you will be scanning the string, and will encounter the `NUL` terminator naturally:

```
char array1[SOMETHING_BIG_ENOUGH];
char array2[2*SOMETHING_BIG_ENOUGH];
char *p = array1;
char *q = array2;
char c;

gets(array1); /* tut-tut */

while ((c = *p++) != '\0') {
    *q++ = c;
    if (c == '\\')
        *q++ = '\\';
}
*q = '\0';
```

This leaves the expanded string in `array2`.

The second case is trickier but uses less space:

```
char array1[2*SOMETHING_BIG_ENOUGH];
char *p;
char *q;

gets(array1); /* tut-tut */

p = &array1[strlen(array1)];
q = &array1[sizeof(array1)];

*--q = '\0';

while (p != array1) {
    if ((*--q = *--p) == '\\')
        *--q = '\\';
}
```

This will leave the expanded string in the upper part of `array1`, with `q` pointing to the first character.

Comment: I will have a play around with the 2 codes to get familiar with, I just read the post about gets, so now I will NEVER use it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a constant string **within your source code**, then you must replicate every backslash character in order for the **compiler** to identify it as a backslash character, rather than as the special character which is indicated by the letter that follows the backslash.

For example:

In `char* str = "C:\not good"`, the compiler will identify the `\n` as a newline character.

In `char* str = "C:\\very good"`, the compiler will identify the `\\` as a backslash character.

But you do not need to worry about this when reading a string from the keyboard **during runtime**.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will make everything after the first `\` to be `\`.

Let's use your example input - `C:\shaving turtle`.

You find a `\` when c is 2.

You set `array1[3]` to `\`.

Then you check the value of `array1[3]`, which is a `\`.

You set `array1[4]` to `\`.

This goes on until you reach the end of the array. At that point, you have also replaced the ending null character by `\`. Your string is not a null terminated string any more.

You can fix the problem making the changes in another string. Steps:

1. Go through the string and count the number of backslashes in it.
2. Create a new string of size `arrayLength+numBackslashes`.
3. Copy the original string to the new string while making sure that you put two backslashes in the new string for every backslash in the original string.

Hope that keeps you moving forward.